# how to create dynamic javascript function

Tags: javascript, submit

When I choice google the submit button value turn into google.com and I choice yahoo submit button value will be change. Here is my attempt.

```js
 <script>
        function goToNewPage() {
            if(document.getElementById('target').value){
                window.open('url','_blank');
            }
        }
        </script>
```

```html
<form name="dropdown">
            <select name="selected" id="target" accesskey="E">
            <option selected>...Select...</option>
            <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
            <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.selected)">
        </form>
```

Comment: There's no submit button in your code ...? You want the button text to change according to what you've selected from the drop-down (says the text)? Or open an URL taken from the selected drop-down value in a new window (says the code)?

Comment: when some choose google and click the submit button and then open a new tab with google link and when some click yahoo then open new tab with yahoo link... At the last line <input type="button" value="Go">

Answer (score 0):

You were VERY close.
This edited version fixes it.  ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durbnpoisn/arg7fa3z/1/))

HTML - Add value for nothing selected.  Strip out the attempt at setting the URL on the way in.  Added an ID for the button, to be used for new function.

```
<form name="dropdown">
        <select name="selected" id="target" accesskey="E" onchange="changeText()">
        <option value="nothing" selected>...Select...</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Go" id="butGo" onclick="goToNewPage()">
    </form>
```

JS - Set URL when the function is called.  Don't put URL in quotes.  It would think it's a string.

```
function goToNewPage() {
    url = document.getElementById('target').value;
    //alert(url)
        if(document.getElementById('target').value!='nothing'){
            window.open(url,'_blank');
        }
    }
```

If you want to change the TEXT on the button, do this:

```
function changeText(){
  url = document.getElementById('target').value;
    if (url=='http://www.google.com') {
    document.getElementById('butGo').value = 'Google'
  }
  if (url=='http://www.yahoo.com/') {
    document.getElementById('butGo').value = 'Yahoo'
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you boss.